# Slack Python API message is not being formatted and channels/names are not linked

Tags: python, formatting, slack-api

I am using [python-slackclient](https://github.com/slackhq/python-slackclient) and messages I am sending are not being formatted and channel and usernames are not being linked. I tried both RTM and also API call, in both cases it fails.

Here is my code:

```
from slackclient import SlackClient

token = 'token'
sc = SlackClient(token)
team_join_event = 'team_join'
message = ('Hi! \n\nPublic channel - <#C06VBR8UT|general>\n\n'
           'Private channel #sports.\n\n Admin - <@U06VBQ8TB|v>')

if sc.rtm_connect():
    user_id = 'U2T0SF1U0'
    response = sc.api_call('im.open', user=user_id)
    dm_channel_id = response['channel']['id']
    # sc.rtm_send_message(dm_channel_id, message)
    sc.api_call(
        'chat.postMessage', channel=dm_channel_id, text=message,
        link_names=1)
else:
    print ("Connection Failed, invalid token?")
```

Here is how it appears:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered raising an issue on the library you're using?

Comment: I will do now. At first I assumed I am making some mistake

Comment: Have you tried passing `<#C06VBR8UT>` instead of `<#C06VBR8UT|general>` ?

Comment: ^Yes, I have. It did not work. It gets changed to `#general` but its not linked